# Remove all array formulas programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet contains an array in the column 'E' where it was group into separate sub-category as below snapshot. How could I remove the array from the entire column 'E' in VBA instead of manually delete it using Find & Select > Go to special > Current Array > Delete?

Any help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder perhaps?

Comment: Not all row in the column 'E' contains an array. There were 5 - 10 empty adjacent rows with the next sub-category which is I need to select and delete it multiple times.

Comment: But did you try the macro recorder?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! I should try it at first before considering posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution to remove all array formulas in column E would be to loop through the column and check the [Range.HasArray property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasarray) in each cell.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveAllArrayFormulasInColumnE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "E").HasArray Then
            ws.Cells(iRow, "E").CurrentArray.ClearContents
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

To make that even faster you can jump in the loop to the end of current array you delete. This way you have less cells to check.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveAllArrayFormulasInColumnE_Quicker()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "E").HasArray Then
            Dim JumpRow As Long
            JumpRow = iRow - 1 + ws.Cells(iRow, "E").CurrentArray.Rows.Count
            ws.Cells(iRow, "E").CurrentArray.ClearContents
            iRow = JumpRow
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will scan down column **E** and remove any array formulas in that column:

```
Sub ArrayKiller()
    Dim rng As Range, rKill As Range
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Set rng = Intersect(rng, Range("E:E"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each r In rng
        If r.HasArray Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(r, rKill)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If rKill Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    rKill.Clear
    
End Sub
```